# How to convert this React Class Component to a Function Component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to convert class component to a function component but it is unsuccessful. This is the class component I want to convert:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {users: []}

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => this.setState({ users }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Users</h1>
        <ul>
        {this.state.users.map(user =>
          <li key={user.id}>{user.username}</li>
        )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is unsuccessful attempt to convert class component to a function component

```
import React, {setState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App () {
  const state = {users: []};

  const componentDidMount = () => {
    fetch('/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => setState({ users }));
  }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Users</h1>
        <ul>
        {state.users.map(user =>
          <li key={user.id}>{user.username}</li>
        )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );

}

export default App;
```

Help me if you can

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook (which is not available in functional components), you should be using the `useEffect` hook. On the useEffect hook, you set an empty array as the [dependency array](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) such that it will only run when the component is first mounted.

In addition, you should be using the `useState` hook to maintain component state.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
fetch('/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => setUsers(users));
}, []);

return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <ul>
    {users.map(user =>
      <li key={user.id}>{user.username}</li>
    )}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `useEffect` and pass in an empty array as a second argument, so that it's executed only once after the component is mounted, which will be similar to what `componentDidMount` does when using classes.

To manage the state use `useState`, which returns a stateful value and a function to update it:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App () {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => setUsers(users));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Users</h1>
      <ul>
        {state.users.map(user =>
          <li key={user.id}>{user.username}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before React 16.8 functional components were only used as stateless/presentational components and were only supposed to re-render if on there properties were changed.

After React 16.8 a new concept of Hooks was introduced which allowed developers to have a state inside a functional components as well. Though there are some differences in approach for this new concept and the old class components approach, the transition from Class component and state component is very simple. You just have to use `useState` hook for creating a state and for all the side effects in your component, like the Fetch API call, use `useEffect` hook.

The first change in your component would be to create/use a state as

```
let [users, setUsers] = React.useState([])
```

With this change you will be able to access your users state by directly using `users` variable rather then using `this.state.users`, pretty neet. Also, now for updating the state you would use the new function `setUsers` which will update the state for you and then re-render the component. You can read more about this hook in [React useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

The second change in your component would be to move your Fetch API call from the component did mount to the `useEffect` hook.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  fetch('/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => this.setUsers(users));
}, [])
```

Notice how the second argument is an empty array, well this is just the way of telling React that this `useEffect` hook only needs to be run once (that is this component is first rendered, or you can say when this component is mounted). React run all `useEffect` hooks after every render so this is very important. You can read more about this in [Skipping Effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

Now, your component will look more like:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
fetch('/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => setUsers(users));
}, []);

return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <ul>
    {users.map(user =>
      <li key={user.id}>{user.username}</li>
    )}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```